# Replace every 4th occurence of char "_" with "@" in multiple files

Tags: bash, perl, awk, sed

I am trying to replace every 4th occurrence of "_" with "@" in multiple files with bash.

E.g.

```
foo_foo_foo_foo_foo_foo_foo_foo_foo_foo..
```

would become

```
foo_foo_foo_foo@foo_foo_foo_foo@foo_foo...

#perl -pe 's{_}{++$n % 4 ? $& : "@"}ge' *.txt
```

I have tried perl but the problem is this replaces every 4th _ carrying on from the last file. So for example, some files the first _ is replaced because it is not starting each new file at a count of 0, it carries on from the previous file.

I have tried:

```
#awk '{for(i=1; i<=NF; i++) if($i=="_") if(++count%4==0) $i="@"}1' *.txt
```

but this also does not work.

Using sed I cannot find a way to keep replacing every 4th occurrence as there are different numbers of _ in each file. Some files have 20 _, some have 200 _. Therefore, I cant specify a range.

I am really lost what to do, can anybody help?

Comment: Assuming your files contain more than 1 line each - do you want to replace every 4th occurrence in each line or across the whole file? Please provide a [mcve] with more than just 1 partial line of sample input (i.e. no ellipses) and the associated expected output to truly demonstrate your requirements. Also state if your input files are each small enough to fit in memory or if we can't assume that.

Answer (score 5):

You just need to reset the counter in the perl one using `eof` to tell when it's done reading each file:

```sh
perl -pe 's{_}{++$n % 4 ? "_" : "@"}ge; $n = 0 if eof' *.txt
```

Answer (score 5):

This MAY be what you want, using GNU awk for RT:

```
$ awk -v RS='_' '{ORS=(FNR%4 ? RT : "@")} 1' file
foo_foo_foo_foo@foo_foo_foo_foo@foo_foo..
```

It only reads each `_`-separated string into memory 1 at a time so should work no matter how large your input file, assuming there are `_`s in it.

It assumes you want to replace every 4th `_` across the whole file as opposed to within individual lines.

Answer (score 1):

With your shown samples, please try following `awk` program. Have created an `awk` variable named `fieldNum` where I have assigned `4` to it, since OP needs to enter `@` after every 4th `_`, you can keep it as per your need too.

```
awk -v fieldNum="4" '
BEGIN{ FS=OFS="_" }
{
  val=""
  for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){
    val=(val?val:"") $i (i%fieldNum==0?"@":(i<NF?OFS:""))
  }
  print val
}
'  Input_file
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple `sed` would handle this:

```sh
s='foo_foo_foo_foo_foo_foo_foo_foo_foo_foo'
sed -E 's/(([^_]+_){3}[^_]+)_/\1@/g' <<< "$s"

foo_foo_foo_foo@foo_foo_foo_foo@foo_foo
```

**Explanation:**

- `(`: Start capture group #1

  - `([^_]+_){3}`: Match Match 1+ of non-`_` characters followed by a `_`. Repeat this group 3 times to match 3 such words separated by `_`
  - `[^_]+`: Match 1+ of non-`_` characters
- `)`: End capture group #1
- `_`: Match a `_`
- Replacement is `\1@` to replace 4th `_` with a `@`

Comment: I think `_` is counted for whole file, not line wise

Comment: I have read question again but it is not completely clear to me. I am waiting for his feedback to edit or delete my answer.

Comment: Yeah, agree that it isn't clear, it could be single line too...

Answer (score 1):

With GNU `sed`:

```sh
sed -nsE ':a;${s/(([^_]*_){3}[^_]*)_/\1@/g;p};N;ba' *.txt
```

`-n` suppresses the automatic printing, `-s` processes each file separately, `-E` uses extended regular expressions.

The script is a loop between label `a` (`:a`) and the branch-to-label-`a` command (`ba`). Each iteration appends the next line of input to the pattern space (`N`). This way, after the last line has been read, the pattern space contains the whole file(*). During the last iteration, when the last line has been read (`$`), a substitute command (`s`) replaces every 4th `_` in the pattern space by a `@` (`s/(([^_]*_){3}[^_]*)_/\1@/g`) and prints (`p`) the result.

When you will be satisfied with the result you can change the options:

```sh
sed -i -nE ':a;${s/(([^_]*_){3}[^_]*)_/\1@/g;p};N;ba' *.txt
```

to modify the files in-place, or:

```sh
sed -i.bkp -nE ':a;${s/(([^_]*_){3}[^_]*)_/\1@/g;p};N;ba' *.txt
```

to modify the files in-place, but keep a `*.txt.bkp` backup of each file.

(*) Note that if you have very large files this could cause memory overflows.

Comment: Don't forget GNU sed has the `-z` option which can also be combined with the `-s` or `-i` option. So `sed -Esz  's/(([^_]*_){3}[^_]*)_/\1@/g' file` works too.

Comment: Yep but what if the files also contain NUL characters?

Answer (score 0):

With `GNU awk`

```sh
$ cat ip.txt
foo_foo_foo_foo_foo_foo_foo_foo_foo_foo
123_45678_90
_

$ awk -v RS='(_[^_]+){3}_' -v ORS= '{sub(/_$/, "@", RT); print $0 RT}' ip.txt
foo_foo_foo_foo@foo_foo_foo_foo@foo_foo
123_45678_90
@
```

- `-v RS='(_[^_]+){3}_'` set input record separator to cover sequence of four `_` (text matched by this separator will be available via `RT`)
- `-v ORS=` empty output record separator
- `sub(/_$/, "@", RT)` change last `_` to `@`
- Use `-i inplace` for inplace editing.

Answer (score -1):

If the count should reset for each line:

```sh
perl -pe's/(?:_[^_]*){3}\K_/\@/g'
```

```
$ cat a.txt
foo_foo_foo_foo_foo_foo_foo_foo_foo_foo
foo_foo_foo_foo_foo_foo_foo_foo_foo_foo

$ perl -pe's/(?:_[^_]*){3}\K_/\@/g' a.txt a.txt
foo_foo_foo_foo@foo_foo_foo_foo@foo_foo
foo_foo_foo_foo@foo_foo_foo_foo@foo_foo
foo_foo_foo_foo@foo_foo_foo_foo@foo_foo
foo_foo_foo_foo@foo_foo_foo_foo@foo_foo
```

---

If the count shouldn't reset for each line, but should reset for each file:

```sh
perl -0777pe's/(?:_[^_]*){3}\K_/\@/g'
```

The `-0777` cause the whole file to be treated as one line. This causes the count to work properly across lines.

But since a new a match is used for each file, the count is reset between files.

```
$ cat a.txt
foo_foo_foo_foo_foo_foo_foo_foo_foo_foo
foo_foo_foo_foo_foo_foo_foo_foo_foo_foo

$ perl -0777pe's/(?:_[^_]*){3}\K_/\@/g' a.txt a.txt
foo_foo_foo_foo@foo_foo_foo_foo@foo_foo
foo_foo_foo@foo_foo_foo_foo@foo_foo_foo
foo_foo_foo_foo@foo_foo_foo_foo@foo_foo
foo_foo_foo@foo_foo_foo_foo@foo_foo_foo
```

---

To avoid that reading the entire file at once, you could continue using the same approach, but with the following added:

```perl
$n = 0 if eof;
```

Note that `eof` is not the same thing as `eof()`! See [`eof`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/eof).